# Not received response from PayPal after making a Payment

Tags: php, paypal

We have added a live seller PayPal account and made $1 amount paid with a
 live buyer **PayPal** account But I am not getting any response in return URL.
        We are using below URL:

**URL** : cgi-bin/webscr

and we have posted some parameter:

```
    cmd = _xclick
    amount = 1
    currency_code = USD
    return = [link removed]
    custom = live seller PayPal email id
    business = live seller PayPal email id
    delivery_service
```

But we are not getting any response in return URL.
Please let us know where is a mistake and why we are facing this issue.

Comment: It's working with some email ids but not working with another email id if problem is related to email id please consider this also.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and find out that we need to enabled Auto Return and Payment data transfer with seller account.